# PHP - Showing two arrays in one line chart

Tags: php, graph, charts, linechart

I have 2 arrays;

```
x = 800,1650,2450,3200,4150,5250,6200,7150,8000

y = 800,850,800,750,950,1100,950,950,850
```

I want to show them in one line chart. 'Array x' will be my X-Axis and 'Array y' will be my Y-Axis.

Also I combined those 2 arrays in one array,

```
$arrgraph = array_combine($y, $x);
```

If I can show it in my chart, it's OK too.

I'm a rookie on php, I searched but couldn't find how to do it. All examples are about only one array. Is there anyone help me about it ? Or can I create that chart with HTML ?

[image: I want my graph like this]

Thank you !

Comment: There is no function `do_graph($x, $y);` in PHP, you'll need to find a library for that. Also, getting recommendations for libraries is not on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I understand, can I do that with HTML ? Or do I need to find a library for that too ?

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can do it with the support of CanvasJS library

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function () {
    var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
    {
      title:{
      text: "Multi-Series Line Chart"  
      },
      data: [
      {        
        type: "line", //you can echo php array here as dataPoints variable
        dataPoints: [
        { x: 10, y: 21 },
        { x: 20, y: 25},
        { x: 30, y: 20 },
        { x: 40, y: 25 },
        { x: 50, y: 27 },
        { x: 60, y: 28 },
        { x: 70, y: 28 },
        { x: 80, y: 24 },
        { x: 90, y: 26}
      
        ]
      }
      ]
    });

    chart.render();
  }
  </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[For more details visit Basic Multi-Series Chart](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/basics-of-creating-html5-chart/multi-series-charts/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! But is there any way that I can do it without entering digits manually to dataPoints ? Can I take them directly from the array(s) ?

Comment: look my comment in code "//you can echo php array here as dataPoints variable" u can make dataPoint array using foreach from php array